# How to get no of days by subtracting two datefields?

Tags: apex

Integer dayDifference;

```
dayDifference = Integer.valueOf(Employment_End_Date__c) - 
                                                 Integer.valueOf(Employment_Start_Date__c);
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
Integer noOfDays = startDate.daysBetween(endDate);
```

See [Date Class Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_daysBetween)

**Edit:**

If you want to find Year, Month and Days you have to try several combos:

Like to find NoOfMonths you can use this method:

```
Integer monthsBetween = firstDate.monthsBetween(secondDate);
```

Then by dividing this by 12 you will get the years.

Comment: but need to calculate no of years...please help me

Comment: See my updated answer.